# control reaches end of non-void function c programming using Xcode

Tags: c

Inventory2.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "inventory2.h"

item_t *inventory[30];
int next=0;

int getNextId() {
    static int id=0;
    return id++;
}

void printItem(item_t *p){
    printf("\n\tpart name: %s", p->name);
    printf("\n\tpart number: %s", p->partNo);
    printf("n\tpart quantity: %d", p->quantity);
    printf("\n\tpart price: %f", p->price);
    printf("n\t\tpart cost: %f", p->cost);

}
printInventory() {
    register int i;
    for(i=0; i<next; i++) {
        printItem(inventory[i]);

    }

} <-THIS IS WHERE THE ERROR OCCURS

int createItem() {
    item_t *p;
    char buf[50];
    buf[0] = '\0';

    p = (item_t*) malloc(sizeof(item_t));
    if(!p) {

        printf("ERROR: no memory for createItem()\n");
        return FALSE;
    }

    p->id=getNextId();
    printf("\n\tEnter part name: ");
    fgets(p->name, 50, stdin);
    p->name[strlen(p->name)-1] = '\0';

    printf("\n\tEnter part number ");
    fgets(p->partNo, 30, stdin);
    p->partNo[strlen(p->partNo)-1] = '0';

    printf("\n\tEnter part quantity: ");
    fgets(buf, 50, stdin);
    buf[strlen(buf)-1] = '\0';
    p->quantity = atoi(buf);

    printf("n\tEnter part price: ");
    fgets(buf, 50, stdin);
    buf[strlen(buf)-1] = '\0';
    p->price = (float) atof(buf);

    printf("n\tEnter part cost: ");
    fgets(buf, 50, stdin);
    buf[strlen(buf)-1] = '\0';
    p->cost = (float) atof(buf);

    inventory[next++] = p;
    return TRUE;
} 

int writeInventory() {
    FILE *fp;
    int num, i;
    item_t*p;

    fp = fopen("inventory.db", "rb");
    for(i=0; i<next; i++){
        p = (item_t*) malloc(sizeof(item_t));
        if(!p) {
            printf("ERROR: no memory for createItem()\n");
            return FALSE;
        }
        inventory[i] = p;
        num = fread(inventory[i], sizeof(item_t), 1, fp);
        if(num == 0) {
            return -1;
        }

        next ++;

    }
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

main 2.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>    
#include "inventory2.h"

int mainMenu (){

    char buf[50], *p;
    buf[0] = '\0';

    printf("\n\tSelect from the following commandsL (L)ist, (A)dd, (R)emove,         (I)mport, (E)xport, or (Q)uit: ");
    fgets(buf, 50, stdin);
    buf[strlen(buf) -1] = '\0';
    p = _strupr(buf);
    switch(*p) {
        case 'L':
            printInventory();
            break;
        case 'A':
            createItem();
            break;
        case 'R':
        case 'I':
            readInventory();
            break;
        case 'E':
        case 'Q':
            writeInventory();
            return FALSE;
        default:
            printf("\n\t\tERROR: invalid option selected!\n");
    }
    return TRUE;
}

int main (void) {

    item_t *i;
    int loop = TRUE;

    while (loop) {
        loop= mainMenu();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

inventory 2.h

```
#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0

typedef struct {
    int id;
    char name[50];
    char partNo[30];
    float price;
    float cost;
    int quantity;
}   item_t;

int createItem();
int writeInventory();
item_t *readInventory();
int printInventory(void);
```

Create an Inventory Control Program, called ICP.exe.  This program will provide the user with a menu of actions to control inventory, which include: list the inventory, create an item, add inventory, remove inventory, delete item, import and export database.

An inventory item has a: Unique ID, Part NO, Names, Quantity, and Sale Price, and Unit Price.

Load a database with the following items:

1. SNK809a Seiko Automatic Men's Watch, 10, $75, $70.
2. SR400 Yamaha 400cc Motorcycle, 3, $5,999, $4,000.
3. Soundlink-Coral Bose Bluetooth Speaker in Coral Red, 20, $129, $89.

Demonstrate loading/creating a database of inventory, creating new items, adding to inventory, removing from inventory, and saving the database.

Capture your output with the snipping tool.

A menu might look like the following, but the student is free to create a different interface, if it is more intuitive.

c:\users\dbs0011\icp.exe

Welcome to the Inventory Control Program!

select from the following (L)ist, (C)reate, (A)dd, (R)emove, (I)mport, or (E)xport:> I

enter the DB name to import:> first.db

first.db imported.

select from the following (L)ist, (C)reate, (A)dd, (R)emove, (I)mport, or (E)xport:> I

Build the Import and Export functions last as we will not cover files until right before the end of this project.  Use dynamic memory allocation for your records.  Each interface option should be a separate function.  Use structures to define your inventory items.  Use separate C files to encapsulate your user interface, data storage and test functions.

Comment: Please format your SQL statements, that improves readabilty and increases the chance for an answer.

Comment: So? You didn't declare a return type for `printInventory()`, therefore it implicitly returns `int`. You're missing a `void` there, just as the error message reads. Voting to close this as "simple typo".

Comment: BTW, there are more `void`s missing: Empty argument lists mean *unspecified* arguments, to express **no** arguments, you write `void`. Your function signature should be `void printInventory(void)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
printInventory() {
register int i;
for(i=0; i<next; i++) {
    printItem(inventory[i]);

}

} <-THIS IS WHERE THE ERROR OCCURS
```

in old school C. If you don't specify a return type for a function it defaults to `int`. In the above case `printInventory` has no return type so the compiler is expecting an `int` to be returned.

There is no `return` statement as the last statement in your function so the compiler does not know what value to return.

Fix by:

1. Setting an explicit return type of void.
2. **OR** adding `return 0;` as the last statement of your function.

I thought this was fixed in modern C. But I don't know how XCode invokes the compiler.

Comment: *implicit int* is **still** part of the most recent (C11) standard. It's obsolete, but not yet removed. So at best, you can expect a compiler warning.